# Foreign phone, stuck on 2G

Tags: 3g, gsm

I am currently working on a Coolpad 8150, a Chinese phone running Android 2.3.7. It is connected to T-Mobile (in the United States) and can place calls successfully. However, it is stuck on 2G. I have been lead to believe the phone supports 3G, though I may be mistaken. How may I further pursue this issue?

When I scan for networks, I only see networks marked 2G, like T-Mobile (2G).

In status, it appears I am still marked as using the China Mobile network operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at [this](http://www.chinatronic.com/products.php/Coolpad-8150/cPath,1),

> GSM:900/1800/1900 Mhz,3G TD-SCDMA 2010-20250 MHZ

And scrolling on down a bit on that page under the '*Data Application Features*'...

> Data Service  GPRS;EDGE;TD-SCDMA

That would explain it, no UMTS/HSPA/HSPA+ mentioned in the spec of that hardware, as that would be required to have [T-Mobile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-Mobile_USA) operating to enable 3G data.

It may be basically a cheap and cheerful but crippled phone, but only for a certain market segment, if there is no supporting data protocol support such as UMTS/HSPA/HSPA+, it will fall back on 2G.

Comment: Am I correct in recalling that T-Mobile no longer supports data transfer over their 2G network? I ask because I am thus afflicted.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your phone is using china mobile's td- protocol. In the rest of the world all phones are CDMA or GSM. Thus yours is a 3rd strange Chinese type. If you had a China Unicom Coolpad you would be able to use it just fine. You are out of luck as this only works in china, except for calling.